# Why android Development Tools eclipse can not resolve packages from different API's?

Tags: android

Why android Development Tools eclipse can not resolve packages from different API's? 
I am getting an errors in android development tool eclipse. its saying that packages can  not resolved to  API 17.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have to download and install the other Android APIs through your Android SDK Manager in Eclipse/Android Development Tools IDE. To do that, please follow these steps:

1. Open a Java class file in your Android project or even an XML Manifest file.
2. Open the 'Window' tab at the top of the IDE application.
3. Then, choose the option Android SDK Manager
4. Tick of all the Android API versions that you want (e.g. API 15 - Android 4.0.3)
5. If it can't be resolved to API 17, then API 17 - Android 4.2.2 is what you will have to tick.

That should then download all the API versions of Android that you need and it should resolve some of the issues.